# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'utility' object has no attribute 'channel'

Tags: python, discord.py

i have an error and i can't resolve it
the error is the title
i have already tested in other situations

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

class utility(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Cog utility pronto!")

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f"Pong! {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms")

    @commands.command()
    async def clear(ctx, amount=5):
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
        await ctx.send(f"{amount}Messaggi eliminati")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(utility(client))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands in a cog are still methods of an instance of the cog.  The first argument passed to them is always the instance

```
class utility(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Cog utility pronto!")

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f"Pong! {round(self.client.latency * 1000)}ms")

    @commands.command()
    async def clear(self, ctx, amount=5):
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
        await ctx.send(f"{amount}Messaggi eliminati")
```

Comment: So when i have this error  I need to add "self" in every Cog commands bracket 
right?
but the .ping command does not work it says:

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'client' is not defined

Comment: You need to access `client` through `self`: `await ctx.send(f"Pong! {round(self.client.latency * 1000)}ms")`

Comment: Patrick really thank now i have learner how to use "self" well